# Apply different CSS styles to Joomla smart search autocomplete suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla3.0, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the Smart Search module and component on a website with auto complete suggestions enabled. The module's auto complete suggestions are styled differently than the component's. See the attached screenshots for reference. The `autocomplete-suggestions` divs are being loaded just before the closing `</body>` tag in the HTML. The component's div is rendered before the module's, but they are indistinguishable from each other. It seems that the jQuery autocomplete script knows which one is which, so would customizing the script be the way to go? I know this would be editing core files, but I am no sure there is any way around it.

**Component HTML template file JavaScript**

```
var suggest = jQuery('#q').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '" . JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_finder&task=suggestions.suggest&format=json&tmpl=component') . "',
    paramName: 'q',
    minChars: 1,
    maxHeight: 400,
    width: 300,
    zIndex: 9999,
    deferRequestBy: 500
```

[image: Smart search module][image: Smart search component]

Answer (score 0):

Most of Joomla! modules/components styles can be overwritten at some point, you just need to create a file on your theme.

`/templates/{your-theme-name}/html/{name-of-the-search-module}/custom.php`

then, you can copy / paste the content of the original php file on the new php file.